# How to delete / clear all product reviews in magento?

Tags: magento, review

How to delete / clear all product reviews in magento?

Answer (score 4):

Go to Catalog -> Reviews and Ratings -> Customer Reviews -> All Reviews

There are checkboxes and you can take the "Delete" action in the upper right.

Answer (score 4):

```
truncate table `rating_option_vote`; 
truncate table `rating_option_vote_aggregated`;
truncate table `review`; 
truncate table `review_detail`; 
truncate table `review_entity_summary`; 
truncate table `review_store`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to delete all of the tables, just the main one (review) and the aggregated (review_entity_summary), they use foreign keys and are set to cascade on delete of parent.

You can just run the following:

```
DELETE FROM review;
DELETE FROM review_entity_summary;
DELETE FROM rating_option_vote;
DELETE FROM rating_option_vote_aggregated;
```

That should help remove any old reviews.